# How to create a function that replaces an array with a new array in C

Tags: c

I have looked all over the Internet trying to find a solution to this and tried all sorts of different arrangements of my code but was unable to find anything that worked or could produce the right result. Basically, I want to have a function that takes in an already-created array as a parameter, creates a new array based on the previous array and based on the value of some other parameter, and then replaces the original array that was used as a parameter with the newly created array. The code would look something like this:

```
void function(double *array, double other_parameter)
 {
  /* do some calculations involving the array and the parameter */
  double new_array[/* some # */] = /* some expression */;
  *array = *new_array;
 }

main()
 {
  double *x[/* some # */];
  x[0]=/* some # */;x[1]=/* some # */;x[2]=/* some # */,...
  double par = /* something */
  function(x,par);
  printf("x =\n%f\n%f\n",x[0],x[1],...)
 }
```

All the commented portions simply represent whatever the specific tasks are I want to execute with this array and what values I specifically chose to give it, which are not important. What I am trying to figure out is what changes need to be made to the notations I used for the arrays, pointers, and parameters; and which places I need to make those changes to get the desired result. If necessary the size of the original array could be input as an additional parameter into the function if that is the only way to get this to work. I will also add that the size of the new array will not always be the same as that of the original (it will depend on the parameters).

I really appreciate any help anyone could give me; I have been tinkering around with the code for many long hours and so far have not gotten anything to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ever allocate an array in C, you can never pass it back up the stack. (i.e. back to the calling function)

In order to create arrays and send them back up, you need to use `malloc()`

```
double* my_ar = malloc(sizeof(double) * ar_size);
...
free(my_ar);
```

If you want to then expand that array

```
my_ar = realloc(my_ar, sizeof(double) * new_size);
```

This will either free your previous array and create a new one of equal size and the same contents OR it will expand your previous array in place.

If you want to duplicate your array

```
#include <string.h>
...
double* new_ar = malloc(my_ar, sizeof(double) * new_ar_size);
memcpy(new_ar, my_ar, MIN(ar_size, new_ar_size) * sizeof(double));
```

Comment: +1, for the valuable information. Pardon me for my intrusion, but in order to allocate contiguous memory location, aren't we suppose to use `calloc`, instead of `malloc`(which is basically used to allocate memory to objects like structs, unions and all). Can we use `realloc` with `calloc` too. I am too new to `C`, hope you won't mind asking such question :-)

Comment: @GagandeepBali SO is all about questions! `calloc` is used if you want to clear your block first. So, for example, a string (`char*`) should probably be `calloc`'d. If you plan on keeping track of how large your array is without a terminating marker, then `calloc` is unnecessary. The difference in implementation is that `malloc` gives you the space, but it's filled with whatever was last there (so junk). `calloc` gives you the space and clears it for you. `calloc` is more or less a `malloc` followed by a `memset`

Comment: Wow, this thingy related to `malloc` and `calloc` is really informative. Thankyou for sharing it :-) , now I won't forget this.

Comment: Thank you for answering, Ryan Amos. I tried using what you said to do, but I still could not get it to work. What would I type in as the function parameter and inside the body of the function? Right now I have:      
`void func (double* arr)      
{      
    free(arr);      
    arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(double) * new_size);      
    arr[0]=some_num;arr[1]=some_num;...      
}      

main()      
{      
double* arr = malloc(sizeof(double) * size);      
arr[0]=some_num;arr[1]=some_num;...      
func(arr);      
}`     This still didn't give me the right results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't free it first. Also, return `arr` after you're done with it and reassign it. `arr` might (probably will) be different after you've `realloc`'d it. Free `arr` at the end of `main()`